# Are scripts hosted at Google cached accross multiple sites?

Tags: jquery, caching

If I visit 1 website www.abc.com that has a reference to say [jQuery hosted at Google Code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js), and then I visit a 2nd website www.xyz.com that has the same reference - will the file be cached across both websites? i.e. will it re-download it on the 2nd website, or just use it from cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Also, if you use Google's loading api you get even faster loads then by just using the cache as it will use Google's [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Delivery_Network). For example:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=[inset Google API key here]">
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

It will use the cache. This is the exact reason why they are hosted by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is the point of using the library hosted on their site.